# kubernetes mkdir in entrypoint of a container as non root user

Tags: kubernetes, permissions

I have a Kubernetes Deployment spec. In that, I am running by Pod container as a non-root user. In addition to that, I want to set up some directory structures for the container process. Therefore, I change the container entry point command by specifying the requirements.

```
spec:
  containers:
    - command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - mkdir -p /mnt/service/path && exec /etc/user/entrypoint
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 100000
        runAsGroup: 100000
```

However, mkdir does not get permission to create a directory with a non-root user.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/mnt/service/path': Permission denied
```

Is there any workaround to create a directory in the entry point?

Comment: Seems like an usecase for `emptyDir` volume. Please consider checking about emptyDir volumes in documentation

Comment: @P.... Your solution did work in test setup, ideally it shouldnt work right? because  ```/mnt``` should be created with userid ```100000``` but i see it got created by root user.i have checked that emptyDir documentation could not find explanation of this behavior. for my own edification  please explain this behavior.

Comment: @confusedgenius for that, I think we need `fsGroup`. Also, it would set the group of `/mnt/service/path` , not `/mnt` or `/mnt/service`

Comment: Also, creating a path under `/mnt` as a non-root user generally is a bit difficult in most GNU/Linux distributions…

Comment: @confusedgenius Use an init-container run under root and create the directory with appropriate permissions.

Comment: Thanks @P....  fsgroup will be the perfect option..

Comment: @Geek-bit : Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.